# A program that calculate the factorial of big number

Tags: c, factorial

It's a test in a website, here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>

void Print_Factorial ( const int N );

int main()
{
    int N;
    scanf("%d",&N);
    Print_Factorial(N--);

    return 0;
}

/* your code will be put in here*/ 

#include <math.h>

int getFactLength(int N){
    double length = 0;
    while(N){
        length += log10(N--);
    }
    return (int)length+1;
}

void printFact(int fact[], int length){
    while(length--){
        printf("%d",*fact++);
    }
}

void initialNums(int nums[], int length, int num){
    while(length--){
        *nums++ = num;
    }
}

void Print_Factorial( const int N ){
    if(N < 0){
        printf("Invalid input");
        return ;
    }
        int NT = N;
    if(NT>=0 && NT<15){
        int fact = 1;
        while(NT){
            fact *= NT--;
        }
        printf("%d",fact);
        return ;
    }

    int length = getFactLength(N);
    int fact[length];
    initialNums(fact, length, 0);
    fact[length-1] = 1;
    int lastNoneZeroIndex = length-1;
    while(NT > 1){
        int lengthT = length;
        int carry = 0;
        while(lengthT-- > lastNoneZeroIndex){
            int result = NT*fact[lengthT] + carry;
            fact[lengthT] = result % 10;
            carry = result / 10;
        }
        while(carry){
            fact[--lastNoneZeroIndex] = carry % 10;
            carry /= 10;
        }
        NT--;
    }

    printFact(fact, length);
}
```

I use values from `0` to `20` to test it, all of them are right. But when I submit it in that website, a test case always do not pass. I don't know what that case is. But, there are 5 cases, all test cases are between 0 and 1000, and two of them are no more than 15, one of them is negative, one of them use most time to pass, so I think the case that didnt pass is a number that smaller than 1000. That's all I know, I can't imagine that 1000 was passed, but the number smaller than 1000 didn't pass. I don't know what is wrong with my lovely code. I hope you can watch my code, and find some bugs.

Comment: Try to test you program on big inputs too. For example, have you checked, that your program returns 93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000 if input is 100?

Comment: Your program does in fact compute 1000! correctly. I believe you have a formatting problem.

Comment: You don't print a new line after the factorial. Maybe the automatic chacker expects this. (A new line also flushes the output.)

Comment: the question requires the output must be in one line, but when the number  is too long,it will turn itsellf, how to ensure that the output is in one line?

Comment: i test 100 , its right. i cant find factorial  numbers larger than that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There create a overflow in the fact variable, here you use int type for fact variable. 
For input 13,14, it gives wrong answer.

Solution:

`long long int fact = 1;`

or,

change the condition- `if(NT>=0 && NT<13)`

Comment: thanks very much! youre right . 12! is larger than 0.4 billion,13! will overflow.